Is there a way to enable something along the lines of `C-u` in a hydra?
For instance I want to use a hydra to move columns of an org-table left or right in a hydra, ie not just a single column but a group of them, so the equivalent of C-u X would select the current column and the next X columns, then use the left and right arrow keys to move them left and right.
Another option would be to use C-u X which would execute the following commands X times?
Can that be done in a hydra?

What columns are you talking about? Are you talking about the menu in e.g. the hydra-buffer-menu example? If so, what would moving them up and down look like? I could understand moving the Unmark column before the Mark column but up or down does not make any sense to me.

I'm referring to org-table columns and I've updated the question to reflect it. I also learned that hydras have a hydra-repeat option, so the latter part is solved for few repeats.
